# Add set of points on top of another graph and turn 3D plot to 2D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I have the following function f[x,y] and I figured out how to plot it to a specified domain, that you can observe in the code, but only in plot3D form I am trying to convert it to just a 2D graph. In my first line of code you can see that I tried to define domain in the function command itself but it did not work, it would only work with the plot3D command for some reason.

```
f[x_, y_] := 
x + (x/((x^2) + (y^2))) /; -2 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 2 && 
x^2 + y^2 >= 1;
Plot3D[f[x, y] && x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None]
```

Next I have the points listed below that I need to plot onto the domain and graph specified above. It is supposed to look like a partially obstructed channel with nearly uniform grid in x and y direction (fluid flow).

```
pnts = {{-1.8, 0.2}, {-1.8, 0.4}, {-1.8, 0.6}, {-1.8, 0.8}, {-1.8, 
1.}, {-1.8, 1.2}, {-1.8, 1.4}, {-1.8, 1.6}, {-1.6, 0.2}, {-1.6, 
0.4}, {-1.6, 0.6}, {-1.6, 0.8}, {-1.6, 1.}, {-1.6, 1.2}, {-1.6, 
1.4}, {-1.6, 1.8}, {-1.4, 0.2}, {-1.4, 0.4}, {-1.4, 0.6}, {-1.4, 
0.8}, {-1.4, 1.}, {-1.4, 1.2}, {-1.4, 1.6}, {-1.4, 1.8}, {-1.2, 
0.2}, {-1.2, 0.4}, {-1.2, 0.6}, {-1.2, 0.8}, {-1.2, 1.}, {-1.2, 
1.4}, {-1.2, 1.6}, {-1.2, 1.8}, {-1., 0.2}, {-1., 0.4}, {-1., 
0.6}, {-1., 0.8}, {-1., 1.2}, {-1., 1.4}, {-1., 1.6}, {-1., 
1.8}, {-0.8, 0.2}, {-0.8, 0.4}, {-0.8, 0.6}, {-0.8, 1.}, {-0.8, 
1.2}, {-0.8, 1.4}, {-0.8, 1.6}, {-0.8, 1.8}, {-0.6, 0.2}, {-0.6, 
0.4}, {-0.6, 0.8}, {-0.6, 1.}, {-0.6, 1.2}, {-0.6, 1.4}, {-0.6, 
1.6}, {-0.6, 1.8}, {-0.4, 0.2}, {-0.4, 0.6}, {-0.4, 0.8}, {-0.4,
 1.}, {-0.4, 1.2}, {-0.4, 1.4}, {-0.4, 1.6}, {-0.4, 1.8}, {-0.2, 
0.4}, {-0.2, 0.6}, {-0.2, 0.8}, {-0.2, 1.}, {-0.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 
1.4}, {-0.2, 1.6}, {-0.2, 1.8}, {0., 0.2}, {0., 0.4}, {0., 
0.6}, {0., 0.8}, {0., 1.}, {0., 1.2}, {0., 1.4}, {0., 1.6}, {0., 
1.8}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0.2, 0.6}, {0.2, 0.8}, {0.2, 1.}, {0.2, 
1.2}, {0.2, 1.4}, {0.2, 1.6}, {0.2, 1.8}, {0.4, 0.2}, {0.4, 
0.6}, {0.4, 0.8}, {0.4, 1.}, {0.4, 1.2}, {0.4, 1.4}, {0.4, 
1.6}, {0.4, 1.8}, {0.6, 0.2}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.8}, {0.6, 
1.}, {0.6, 1.2}, {0.6, 1.4}, {0.6, 1.6}, {0.6, 1.8}, {0.8, 
0.2}, {0.8, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.6}, {0.8, 1.}, {0.8, 1.2}, {0.8, 
1.4}, {0.8, 1.6}, {0.8, 1.8}, {1., 0.2}, {1., 0.4}, {1., 
0.6}, {1., 0.8}, {1., 1.2}, {1., 1.4}, {1., 1.6}, {1., 1.8}, {1.2,
 0.2}, {1.2, 0.4}, {1.2, 0.6}, {1.2, 0.8}, {1.2, 1.}, {1.2, 
1.4}, {1.2, 1.6}, {1.2, 1.8}, {1.4, 0.2}, {1.4, 0.4}, {1.4, 
0.6}, {1.4, 0.8}, {1.4, 1.}, {1.4, 1.2}, {1.4, 1.6}, {1.4, 
1.8}, {1.6, 0.2}, {1.6, 0.4}, {1.6, 0.6}, {1.6, 0.8}, {1.6, 
1.}, {1.6, 1.2}, {1.6, 1.4}, {1.6, 1.8}, {1.8, 0.2}, {1.8, 
0.4}, {1.8, 0.6}, {1.8, 0.8}, {1.8, 1.}, {1.8, 1.2}, {1.8, 
1.4}, {1.8, 1.6}};
```

Comment: you can try `h[x_, y_] := x + (x/((x^2) + (y^2)));
Plot3D[h[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
 RegionFunction -> (#^2 + #2^2 >= 1 &)]` and, perhaps, `Show[DensityPlot[h[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
  RegionFunction -> (#^2 + #2^2 >= 1 &)], ListPlot[pnts]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := x + x/(x^2 + y^2);

pnts = {{-1.8, 0.2}, {-1.8, 0.4}, {-1.8, 0.6}, {-1.8, 0.8}, {-1.8, 
    1.}, {-1.8, 1.2}, {-1.8, 1.4}, {-1.8, 1.6}, {-1.6, 0.2}, {-1.6, 
    0.4}, {-1.6, 0.6}, {-1.6, 0.8}, {-1.6, 1.}, {-1.6, 1.2}, {-1.6, 
    1.4}, {-1.6, 1.8}, {-1.4, 0.2}, {-1.4, 0.4}, {-1.4, 0.6}, {-1.4, 
    0.8}, {-1.4, 1.}, {-1.4, 1.2}, {-1.4, 1.6}, {-1.4, 1.8}, {-1.2, 
    0.2}, {-1.2, 0.4}, {-1.2, 0.6}, {-1.2, 0.8}, {-1.2, 1.}, {-1.2, 
    1.4}, {-1.2, 1.6}, {-1.2, 1.8}, {-1., 0.2}, {-1., 0.4}, {-1., 
    0.6}, {-1., 0.8}, {-1., 1.2}, {-1., 1.4}, {-1., 1.6}, {-1., 
    1.8}, {-0.8, 0.2}, {-0.8, 0.4}, {-0.8, 0.6}, {-0.8, 1.}, {-0.8, 
    1.2}, {-0.8, 1.4}, {-0.8, 1.6}, {-0.8, 1.8}, {-0.6, 0.2}, {-0.6, 
    0.4}, {-0.6, 0.8}, {-0.6, 1.}, {-0.6, 1.2}, {-0.6, 1.4}, {-0.6, 
    1.6}, {-0.6, 1.8}, {-0.4, 0.2}, {-0.4, 0.6}, {-0.4, 0.8}, {-0.4, 
    1.}, {-0.4, 1.2}, {-0.4, 1.4}, {-0.4, 1.6}, {-0.4, 1.8}, {-0.2, 
    0.4}, {-0.2, 0.6}, {-0.2, 0.8}, {-0.2, 1.}, {-0.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 
    1.4}, {-0.2, 1.6}, {-0.2, 1.8}, {0., 0.2}, {0., 0.4}, {0., 
    0.6}, {0., 0.8}, {0., 1.}, {0., 1.2}, {0., 1.4}, {0., 1.6}, {0., 
    1.8}, {0.2, 0.4}, {0.2, 0.6}, {0.2, 0.8}, {0.2, 1.}, {0.2, 
    1.2}, {0.2, 1.4}, {0.2, 1.6}, {0.2, 1.8}, {0.4, 0.2}, {0.4, 
    0.6}, {0.4, 0.8}, {0.4, 1.}, {0.4, 1.2}, {0.4, 1.4}, {0.4, 
    1.6}, {0.4, 1.8}, {0.6, 0.2}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.6, 0.8}, {0.6, 
    1.}, {0.6, 1.2}, {0.6, 1.4}, {0.6, 1.6}, {0.6, 1.8}, {0.8, 
    0.2}, {0.8, 0.4}, {0.8, 0.6}, {0.8, 1.}, {0.8, 1.2}, {0.8, 
    1.4}, {0.8, 1.6}, {0.8, 1.8}, {1., 0.2}, {1., 0.4}, {1., 
    0.6}, {1., 0.8}, {1., 1.2}, {1., 1.4}, {1., 1.6}, {1., 1.8}, {1.2,
     0.2}, {1.2, 0.4}, {1.2, 0.6}, {1.2, 0.8}, {1.2, 1.}, {1.2, 
    1.4}, {1.2, 1.6}, {1.2, 1.8}, {1.4, 0.2}, {1.4, 0.4}, {1.4, 
    0.6}, {1.4, 0.8}, {1.4, 1.}, {1.4, 1.2}, {1.4, 1.6}, {1.4, 
    1.8}, {1.6, 0.2}, {1.6, 0.4}, {1.6, 0.6}, {1.6, 0.8}, {1.6, 
    1.}, {1.6, 1.2}, {1.6, 1.4}, {1.6, 1.8}, {1.8, 0.2}, {1.8, 
    0.4}, {1.8, 0.6}, {1.8, 0.8}, {1.8, 1.}, {1.8, 1.2}, {1.8, 
    1.4}, {1.8, 1.6}};

Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  Mesh -> None,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z},
    Blend[{
      Opacity[.67, Blue],
      Opacity[.67, Orange]}, z]],
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 >= 1]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{#[[1]], #[[2]], 0} & /@ pnts]}]]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 >= 1],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[pnts]}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 >= 1],
 Contours -> Range[-2, 2, 0.5],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[pnts]}]
```

[image]